# Can an android process run while screen is locked without WAKE_LOCK?

Tags: android, android-wake-lock

Is WAKE_LOCK the only solution to a background service that is only active when a specific event occurs?

Comment: What is the specific event ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without a wake lock, the device usually goes to sleep a few seconds (30-60, usually) after the screen is locked.

During this period, only the radios are kept on low power to receive calls, SMS and push notifications. Everything else, like your app, will be paused.

If you want to continue working with the screen off, you should obtain a wakelock.